# How is the dual notion of an extensive map called?

Tags: terminology, order-theory, lattice-orders

While reading about closure operators I encountered the following notion:

> **Definition.** Let $A$ be a partially ordered set. A map $f$ from $A$ to $A$ is *extensive* if $a ≤ f(a)$ for every element $a$ of $A$.

I’ve been wondering how the dual notion is called:

> **Question.** How is the property “$f(a) ≤ a$ for every element $a$ of $A$” called?